# How to turn an Array of objects into a nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

Hello I try to get this output

```
{
    name: "Saviole",
    role: "ceo",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Mary",
            role: "supervisorA",
            children: [
                {name: "Anna", role: "worker"}
                ]
        }, {
            name: "Louis",
            role: "supervisorB"
        }]
}
```

These are the functions I wrote:

```
const users = [ 
  {name: "Anna", role: "worker"},
  { name: "Mary", role: "supervisorA" },
  { name: "Louis", role: "supervisorB" },  
  { name: "Saviole", role: "ceo" }
  ];

const recursiveAddToTree = (parent, child, grandChildren, users)=>{
  let tree = {};
users.forEach(( user)=>{
if(user.role===parent){
   tree ={...user}
} else if(user.role===child){
 tree = {...tree, chidren:[...[user]]}
} else {
 users.forEach(userChild=>{ 
   if(userChild.role===child){
   tree = {...tree, children:[...[{...userChild, chidren: [...[user]]}]]}
   }
 })
}
})
return tree;
}

const createSchema = users =>{
return recursiveAddToTree("ceo", "supervisorA","worker", users)
}
```

How do I solve this? I don't understand why it doesn't work as thought

Comment: how would that code have any clue that Anna is under Mary?

Comment: how do you know which superviso to select for a worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a sorted array where all users are orderd by their role under the direct role above and take an object to get a level of the roles. Then iterate and take an array of level for keeping track of the last user and inser the user according to the role/level.

This approach maintains the given order.

```js
const
    users = [
        { name: "Saviole", role: "ceo" },
        { name: "Mary", role: "supervisor" },
        { name: "Anna", role: "worker" },
        { name: "Louis", role: "supervisor" }
    ],
    roles = { ceo: 0, supervisor: 1, worker: 2 },
    tree = [],
    levels = [tree];

users.forEach(user => {
    const level = roles[user.role];
    if (!levels[level]) {
        const
            temp = levels[level - 1],
            last = temp[temp.length - 1];

        levels[level] = [];
        last.children = levels[level];
    }
    levels[level].push(user);
});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How do I split workers between the 2 supervisors? How I can say I want anna inside another group?

Comment: just move the item below the wanted supervisor.

Comment: what does mode mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 issue in your code:

- the foreach will process the users one by one, finishing by the last one: the ceo. But in your code if the processed user is the ceo your tree object is replaced by the user, so all your previous modifications are erased (I think it's the most important issue)
- the roles of the supervisors are "supervisorA" and "supervisorB", but you're checking if the role is "supervisor", it'll never match, you should check if the role start with "supervisor"

Comment: it should be supervisorA and not B sorry for that. How can I loop in order to not overwrite??

Comment: You could decide to order the items before the foreach, or to use multiple loops (first you process the ceo, then the supervisors and at the end the workers)